# Should we have multiple languages on this Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

There are many non-English speaking people that use Substrate. Specifically [Mandarin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mandarin#Noun) for the Chinese community may be a great way to connect with this sub-community that isn't as easy to connect with on other shared platforms.

Should we push to have this SE used for them as well in Mandarin?

Comment: [SE isn't interested in opening new non-english sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32564/why-was-a-proposal-for-a-non-english-site-closed-based-on-a-policy-from-6-years/32565#32565)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an option. Our network-wide policy is that content on our sites must be single-language with the exception of sites about a language - which allow both English and that language. The moderation on those sites is done by bilingual users who are able to review content in both languages.

As this site is not about a language, it must be English-only.

Comment: Is this to prevent fragmenting the community and answerbase? I can see there's good reasons for either stance. I can see the rational for not fragmenting the community.

Comment: It's for a myriad of reasons - moderation is impossible if you don't speak the language, if you only speak English, how do you answer questions asked in other languages? How do you deal with duplicate questions when they happen to be in different languages? What about the UI? Someone who doesn't speak English won't be able to navigate the site since it's only in English... it's just a terrible user experience to have multiple languages on one site - that's why there are separate non-English SO sites.